# Unable to compile class for jsp in tomcat 6.0.2.0

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

Everything is fine according to me but Still i am getting an exception as **"org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: "**

Please look into it

- RootDircetory:- CallActionJsp
- RootDircetory/action.jsp
- RootDircetory/index.html
- RootDircetory/meta-inf
- RootDircetory/web-inf/classes/foo/Person.class
- RootDircetory/web-inf/web.xml

========================================================================

**Index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Index Page</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="action.jsp" method="get">
<p align="left">Password: <input type="text" name="Password" /></p>
<BR>
<br>
<center><input type="SUBMIT" name="SUBMIT" /></center>
</form>
</body>
</html
```

**Person.java**

```
package foo;
public class Person
{
String name ;
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**action.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="foo.*,java.util.Date"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Action JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Standard Actions are used Here.</h1>
<br>
<%
    Person p = new Person();
    Date date = new Date();
    out.print(date);
    String param = request.getParameter("Password");
    out.print("<br>"+param);
%>

<a href="CallActionJsp">Call Again </a>

</body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ActionJsp</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/action.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ActionJsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CallActionJsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Regards
Ankur

Answer (score 1):

Quick guess - `Person` is not found because of a lowercase `web-inf` in `RootDircetory/web-inf/classes/foo/Person.class`?

`WEB-INF` must be an upper case name, could you try renaming it?

Comment: yeah thank you very much!!!
Its working fine now, i was not known with this upper case issue,
thanking you again

Regards,
Ankur

Comment: @AnkurGarg you haven't accepted answers to any of your questions - please consider doing that to get better answers